# Can motherboard reload power without error?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

For few weeks im having an issue with my pc restarting randomly, sometimes even 3+ times within a second (looks like convulsion). Sometimes i can use pc even for a hour or two, sometimes less than a minute. 
Games and other things do not affect on it at all, i even tried running some benchmark tests etc, everything is fine, i cannot find the issue.

I've opened the PSU and it looks pretty good inside, can't see anything burned there.

Can motherboard cause that issue in theory? with no beeps, no errors, just restarts just like shorting power.

ps. Ram and everything else been tested too, everything is fine. The issue can be only PSU or Motherboard.

Comment: Is it over heating?  Did you trying using speedfan or similar to monitor the temps?  Yes, if it is overheated and reboots it could still be overheated and reboot again?  Could be a power issue, you could try a UPS to eliminate power fluctuation if those are a problem.  Did you monitor the voltages on the 5v and 12v lines to make sure they are within +/- 5%?

Comment: @cybernard cooling is fine, i've got water cooling system, the CPU is around 28o . The voltage on BIOS seems normal =( Nothing overheated

Comment: The cpu doesn't have a work load in the BIOS try while running windows.  Then run a benchmark, and see if the voltages change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the **motherboard** after all. Decided to build a new PC with the newest components in the market.